# Open Source API Platform

Tags: open-source, cross-platform

Which Open source API might suitable or suggest to use with the data management as below:

1. Data Inbound management (for internal use only)
2. Data Outbound management (for external provide information)

The development mostly use **C#**, **java**, **python**, **C++**.

I have survey for some option such as **Wso2**, **Gravitee**, **Fusio**.

Above which might suggest to use for long term management?